# Threading with subprocess

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using python 2.7 and new to Threading. I got a class file and run method. But I don't see the run method invoked when I create instances of thread. I am also planning to use `subprocess.Popen` inside the `run` method and get `stdout` of the process for each filename and print the output.

Please tell me what I am missing here for `run` method to be called.

```
class FileScanThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, myFileName):
        print("In File Scan Thread")
        self.mapFile = myFileName
        #myjar=myFileName
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        print self.mapFile

  x= FileScanThread("myfile.txt")
```

Comment: I tried that too (x.start()) but run method is not invoked. Is there any different syntax for python 2.7 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're forgetting to call the mother class constructor to specify target. It's not java, and `run` has no particular meaning. By default, target is `None` and the thread does nothing.

```
import threading

class FileScanThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, myFileName):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self,target=self.run)
        # another syntax uses "super", which is simpler in python 3
        # super().__init__(target=self.run)

        print("In File Scan Thread")
        self.mapFile = myFileName
        #myjar=myFileName
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        print(self.mapFile)

x= FileScanThread("myfile.txt")

x.join()  # when you're done
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want. You aren't calling `__init__` from the class Thread.

```
class FileScanThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, myFileName):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print("In File Scan Thread")
        self.mapFile = myFileName
        #myjar=myFileName
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        print self.mapFile

x = FileScanThread("myfile.txt")
```

I don't think you have to pass target argument to it. At least that's not usually how I do it.

Output:

```
In File Scan Thread
myfile.txt
```

Comment: Right, you only want to use `target` if you want the thread to run an external function. In this case, the class instance is the thread.